# How do I create a generic for an unknown number of argument of a Callable in python?

Tags: python, python-itertools, type-hinting, python-typing

In this programming exercise, I wrote a starmap generator as an equivalent to `itertools.starmap` and aimed to provide accurate type hints. The code snippet below showcases the implementation:

```py
from typing import Callable, Generator, Iterable, Unpack, TypedDict


def starmap[T](func: Callable[..., T], iterable: Iterable[tuple]) -> Generator[T, None, None]:
    yield from map(func, *zip(*iterable))

# test:
import itertools
args = lambda x, y: x + y, [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
assert list(itertools.starmap(*args)) == list(starmap(*args))
```

The challenge now lies in determining how to generically represent the arguments (...) of the func parameter so that their types align with those found in the tuples within the provided iterable. How does one write the generic for the arguments?

I tried adding another generic: `def starmap[T, Args]` and somehow use `typing.Unpack`, but I'm not sure this is what I need here.

Answer (score 0):

Use `typing.TypeVarTuple` and `typing.Unpack`.

```py
from typing import (
    Callable,
    Generator,
    Iterable,
    TypeVar,
    TypeVarTuple,
    Unpack,
)

T = TypeVar("T")
Ts = TypeVarTuple("Ts")


def starmap(
    func: Callable[[Unpack[Ts]], T], iterable: Iterable[tuple[Unpack[Ts]]]
) -> Generator[T, None, None]:
    yield from map(func, *zip(*iterable))


# test:
import itertools


def func(x: int, y: int) -> float:
    return x + y


args = func, [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
assert list(itertools.starmap(*args)) == list(starmap(*args))
```